# Remove recent object from embedded document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoose and node js for development. I want to `$pull` recent object from embedded documents `spas`.

Here is my sample data. Please help me to build mongodb query.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f071322c89b0e2a7c35a25a"),
    "totalPrice" : 0,
    "user" : ObjectId("5ee096ee7febd3408828ce2c"),
    "type" : "SpaService",
    "spas" : [
        {
            "price" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f071322c89b0e2a7c35a25b"),
            "categoryId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e2"),
            "serviceId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e3"),
            "duration" : 60
        },
        {
            "price" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f071328c89b0e2a7c35a25c"),
            "categoryId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e2"),
            "serviceId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e3"),
            "duration" : 60
        },
        {
            "price" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f071363c89b0e2a7c35a25d"),
            "categoryId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e2"),
            "serviceId" : ObjectId("5ebbfd29b117f50dac1039e3"),
            "duration" : 30
        }
    ],
    "listingId" : ObjectId("5ebbf95fb117f50dac1039d1")
}
```

In this example I have 3 `object` in `spas` and I want to pull recent `_id` whose `duration` is 60.
Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you add that query also?

Comment: @Gibbs I was tried but no luck. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by `recent`

Comment: @Gibbs it means remove latest `_id` record from embedded document.

Comment: How do you find that `latest` as you don't have a field. Do you expect to be identified by `ObjectId`?

Comment: @Gibbs yes, I want to remove by latest `ObjectId`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217543/discussion-between-sampat-singh-and-gibbs).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB v4.2 or later, you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) where you can use `$reduce` to find the latest `_id` that has the duration 60. Then apply $filter to eliminate the element with that `_id`.

```
db.collection.update({/* your update condition */ }, [
  {
    $set: {
      spas: {
        $filter: { // 2. use filter to keep elements that has _id that is not equal to the _id we found
          input: "$spas",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this._id",
              {
                $reduce: { // 1. find the element with the latest _id and has duration 60
                  input: "$spas",
                  initialValue: null,
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $and: [
                          { $eq: ["$$this.duration", 60] },
                          { $gt: ["$$this._id", "$$value"] }
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$this._id",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3bXOUBGEyNr)